# Vimeo API issue- Unable to initiate an upload

Tags: php, vimeo-api

Currently while uploading I am receiving below message:

"Unable to initiate an upload. [Unable to upload video. Please get in touch with the app's creator.]"

Can someone please let me know is there any setting I am missing or is there anything to do with code?

FYI - upload permission is enabled.

UPDATE: I am using PHP Vimeo Laravel library, below is the code.

```
 public function postvideo(Request $request){
    $file = $request->file('video');
    $realpath = $file->getRealPath();
    Vimeo::upload($realpath);
}
```

Comment: Can you share some code snippets or provide details about how you are interacting with the API? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @TommyPenner thanks for the kind reply, I have added the code snippet as you mentioned. Please help.

Answer (score 7):

Problem with this mostly is incorrectly generated token, you need to make token with upload option enabled:

[Vimeo generate token pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwydG.png)

As you can see from the image, you need to make an authenticated token, and after that, you will have multiple option choices, where you just need to select "upload".

If all that fails, you can easily debug it at: 
file: vendor/vimeo/vimeo-api/src/Vimeo/Vimeo.php 
method: upload

right before the exception is thrown, you can add die dump or something like that to acquire a message that you probably didn't see, containing useful information about your problem, like, you need to pass user_id in your token, etc.